# Facebook scores api with iOS5.1 - Can read scores... but cant post them

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm new to iOS development, I have successfully integrated facebook login and such... however my problem is with the Score api. i can read the score but i cant seem to post it, i have the publish_actions permission and also am getting back a valid access_token.Not sure what the problem it, here is my code -

```
NSString *accessTokenToUse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.facebook accessToken] ];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   //@"233", @"score",
                                   accessTokenToUse, @"access_token",
                                   nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *paramsB = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"233", @"score",
                                   accessTokenToUse, @"access_token",
                                   nil];
    NSLog(@"APP ACCESS TOKEN: %@",accessTokenToUse);

    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/scores" andParams:paramsB andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"APP_ID/scores" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];
```

***EDIT - Still doesn't work

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"233", @"score", 
                               @"[APP_ACCESS_TOKEN (omitted for stackoverflow)]", @"access_token", nil];
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/[userID]/scores" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

---

EDIT - SOLVED

So bascially i WAS passing in the correct token, however the facebook sdk was overwriting it in Facebook.m to the user's access token. So the fix was simple - whenever i need to pass in the App's token i just add an other parameter < key=@"useAppToken" Value=@"yes" > and in Facebook.m just add an if statement within isSessionValid -

```
- (FBRequest*)openUrl:(NSString *)url
           params:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
       httpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
         delegate:(id<FBRequestDelegate>)delegate {

NSLog(@"PARAMS BFORE: %@ ", params);
[params setValue:@"json" forKey:@"format"];
[params setValue:kSDK forKey:@"sdk"];
[params setValue:kSDKVersion forKey:@"sdk_version"];

if ([self isSessionValid]) {
    if ([params objectForKey:@"useAppToken"] == nil || [params objectForKey:@"useAppToken"] == @"no") {
        [params setValue:self.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    }

}
NSLog(@"PARAMS AFTER: %@ ", params);
[self extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];

FBRequest* _request = [FBRequest getRequestWithParams:params
                                           httpMethod:httpMethod
                                             delegate:delegate
                                           requestURL:url];
[_requests addObject:_request];
[_request addObserver:self forKeyPath:requestFinishedKeyPath options:0    context:finishedContext];
[_request connect];
return _request;
```

}

Be sure to comment out the NSLogs in this... :)

Answer (score 1):

Scores can only be published using application `access_token` and not one for user (which you probably using, it's ok for reading the scores but don't allow you to publish 'em).

Citing the [Scores documentaion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/):

> **Create or update a score for a user**
>   You can post a score or a user by issuing an `HTTP` `POST` request to `/USER_ID/scores` with the app `access_token` as long as you have the `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: +1, basically you do this server side - otherwise users could update their own scores

Comment: Oh wow. thank you for the quick reply!! - So basically i use  access_token/scores?

Comment: Okay so i tried to do access_token/scores instead (even though it didn't make sense) and it didn't update anything

Comment: Sorry just to make it clear... the "me/scores" is the logged in user's USER_ID/scores

Comment: @user1450760, nope, you should use `/me/scores`, but the `access_token` you use is for user (check it with [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)) which need to be substituted with [application `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/)

Comment: So i've tried this and keep getting the - "this method must be called with an app access_token"

Comment: Then you're probably not using the app access token - check with a call to `/me` to make sure it's really the app access token, and make sure the app isn't configured as 'Desktop/native' in the app settings. Note that you'll need to post to `/USER_ID/scores`, not `/me/scores` when using the app access token as 'me' will be the app when using an app access token

Comment: @Igy, oh, forgot for a second that `me` only makes sense with user's `access_token`, thanks for clearing it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/461900043821056

But if you change your app settings to web app instead of native it would work.